# std::regex equivalent of '/g' global modifier

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

In Perl, I can do this:

```
$text = '1747239';
@matches = ($text =~ m/(\d)/g);
# @matches now contains ('1', '7', '4', '7', '2', '3', '9')
```

Using C++ regex matching, what's the best way to replicate this behaviour so 
that I get a match set including all the matches?

I have this at the moment:-

```
compiledRegex = std::regex(regex, std::tr1::regex_constants::extended);
regex_search(text, results, compiledRegex);

int count = results.size();
// Alloc pointer array based on count * sizeof(mystruct).
for ( std::cmatch::iterator match = results.begin(); 
      match != results.end(); 
      ++match )
{
    // Do something with match;
}
```

However this will only give me the first match, just like Perl without the /g which is fine, but I'd like the /g effect.

So, is there a good way to do it, or must I keep running the regex over and over?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should call `regex_search` several times. Its return value specifies whether there are more matches. Each time you call it you get a new match. The iterator returned by results goes over the group submatches defined in your regular expression. The first entry is always the entire match, that's why in your case `count == 1`

```
std::string::const_iterator text_iter = text.cbegin();
compiledRegex = std::regex(regex, std::tr1::regex_constants::extended);

while (regex_search(text_iter, text.end(), results, compiledRegex))
{
    int count = results.size();
    // Alloc pointer array based on count * sizeof(mystruct).
    for ( std::cmatch::iterator group = results.begin();
          group != results.end();
          ++group )
    {
        // If you uses grouping in your search here you can access each group
    }

   std::cout << std::string(results[0].first, results[0].second) << endl;
   text_iter = results[0].second;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's pretty much what I was winding up with, I guess I was hoping for a flag to make regex_search do it. Presumably you need to move the text pointer on to the end of the last match on each iteration?

Comment: @JonB You are right. The iterators instead of string should be used. At the end of each iteration, the search iterator should be updated, using `results[0].second`. I've updated my answer corespodingly.