# Creating Javascript Regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

Is it possible to create a RegExp javascript object, in C++? I'm just curious about it.

Example:

```
const myCLib = require('myCLib');
myCLib("/\\s/", "g"); => return regex object /\g/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has been part of the C++ standard since C++11 and no additional libraries are needed. The default syntax for regular expressions is identical to ECMAScript's (JavaScript's) syntax for regular expressions.

```
#include <regex>

// Note that construction of the regex can be QUITE expensive, and should
// not be done often if you care even a little about performance. Regexes
// are commonly created at global scope.
const std::regex my_regex{"\\s"};

// Raw strings are sometimes more readable...
const std::regex my_regex{R"(\s)"};
```

The /g modifier behavior is achieved by using the regex differently, see [std::regex equivalent of '/g' global modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136699/stdregex-equivalent-of-g-global-modifier)

Comment: Performance depends on the C++ implementation you use, and the particular problem you're solving.  There are three major C++11 implementations I can think of, and they are each different. You can always use a third-party library for regular expressions or compile regexes to code e.g. with Ragel, which can make extremely high-performance parsers if you think it's worth the effort.